# Html Button background repeats itself, but is set to size:100%

Tags: jquery, html, css, button

I am trying to set an image background for a button in HTML. My CSS looks like this:

```
background-image: url("images/Home-Button.png"); 
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Here is [the image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dxkrtcfx0ieq1ot/Home-Button.png?dl=0).
Here is the [image display](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nf6y6ki89lnq2of/Unbenannt.png?dl=0).

It looks like the background repeats itself. This happens to all of my buttons. How can I avoid this?

Sorry for the links to images. This is my first question, so I don't have enough points to display images on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code to:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-clip:padding-box;
```

and now it works, it does not work however with `background-size:cover`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
background-size:cover;
```

> The cover value specifies that the background image should be sized so
>   that it is as small as possible while ensuring that both dimensions
>   are greater than or equal to the corresponding size of the container.

[Reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images#Special_values.3A_.22contain.22_and_.22cover.22).

Example code:

```css
button {
  background:url(http://www.kafkabrigade.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/button-pic.jpg) center / cover no-repeat;
  border:0;
  cursor:pointer;
  width:196px;
  height:220px;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Comment: This cuts the image off at the bottom, or it moves it down:https://www.dropbox.com/s/nf6y6ki89lnq2of/Unbenannt.png?dl=0 and it still repeats

Comment: Without HTML it's guesswork, but it *cannot* repeat like this unless you have `background-clip` set wrong, and/or the dimension of the button not identical to the background image.

Comment: i found the right code and posted it as an answer, thanks for helping.

Comment: While your solution is also fine (like I said - clip setting plays an important part) it's more resilient to use `cover`, and as you can see in the example in this post it works fine.